# Unable to reinstall iMac from 2010 - Yosemite installer or alternatives?

Tags: macos, imac, install

A friend handed me their iMac from 2010 over. The latest version of macOS it is supporting is Yosemite.
I'm trying to reinstall the Mac from scratch but until now without success. Now I'm looking for other options. Here's what I have tried:

- Boot with OPTION+R and try to reinstall. I'm asked to sign in to App Store and eventually get the error message that the requested item is currently unavailable.
- Boot with OPTION+CMD+R and try to do an internet installation. I see a spinning globe and a progress bar and a clock icon showing "24:00". It's been sitting there for a couple of hours.
- Create a bootable USB stick. I downloaded the Yosemite installer but it is a DMG file. To create a bootable stick, I need the .APP file. I cannot get that app file because the DMG/PKG cannot be installed on my Mac (Apple Silicon).
- I am currently downloading a Yosemite.app file from Archive.org - hoping that this will help me but it's taking days to download.

All advice is welcome. Maybe someone has a ready-to-download version of Yosemite (or earlier!)?

Comment: Have you seen this : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420325/415185  You can adapt with Yosemite if necessary.

Comment: Which iMac model exactly? An iMac Mid-2010 should be able to run High Sierra. Try at least El Capitan. See https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2010.html

Comment: I ended up finding an older intel Mac and used it to create a High Sierra installer USB stick.

Comment: Since the OP posted a comment where a High Sierra installer was created using an Intel Mac, I believe this question is a duplicate of the following question. [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)