# Macbook A1342 2009 won't show my bootable USB

Tags: macos, usb, startup, install

I have already ask this question before but I had no answers and I didn't explain many details on it. I will tell you everything about this problem.

I got a MacBook (Model A1342) 2009, I thought it was a great idea to delete everything on the Mac and now I'm stuck with the 4 utilities every time I boot up my MacBook.

I tried installing OS X (El Capitan) but then it says "Require download" something like that, I tried to change the date I was able to continue then I can't go further because I need to log in to my AppleID to continue, I did that but then it says "This item is temporarily unavailable".

I searched on Google why this happens and it seems like Apple doesn't support the service anymore to let us install the OS X in the App Store.
So I needed to make a bootable USB, I downloaded the latest version of El Capitan from the official website of Apple "InstallMacOSX.dmg" (5,78GB), Since I have only one MacBook I tried to make the bootable USB in Windows using a program called "TransMac".

I did format the volume to GUID on my MacBook, I did unplug my USB and did go back to plug it in Windows. I did send the .dmg to TransMac to my USB which made it decompress to a .pkg and made a folder "Install OS X".
Everything must be good right? Well no, I plugged it in my MacBook, I did boot it up by pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and it did bring me to the Boot Manager, it doesn't show my bootable USB.

Although, when I go to the 4 utilities > **Disk Utility**, the MacBook recognizes the bootable USB but doesn't show my bootable USB on the Boot Manager? I used a USB 16GB to do this method, normally everything should be alright, I do not understand, that's why I need help.

Comment: This is a wall of text and hard to read. If you have asked this before then it is better to edit your original question. I suspect after trying to read this that it to was too difficult to read for people to be bothered to work out what you are asking

Comment: @mmmmmm oh sorry, i deleted the original post but i'll try to edit this one

Comment: I'm not sure that the format of the olds Mac os x versions is recognized by Transmac. For information and from a more recent Mac that is not compatible with these old versions, here is the procedure to create a bootable key : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420325/415185  I've never use TransMac.. Good luck. ;-)

Comment: @Jean_JD Doesn't this method only work when you have an OS X? That's impossible to do it when you're stuck on the 4 utilities

Comment: You mean in the terminal in Recovery mode? You find the terminal on top menu bar in Utility. If you can open a terminal, it would be nice to have the system version of this Recovery by the command `sw_vers`

Comment: @Jean_JD Ok i'll try but just to let you know, the sudo command to do not work on this terminal, it says that it doesn't exists

Comment: In Recovey Mode you are Root, so you don't need use sudo. But somes commands may not be presents.

Comment: @Jean_JD I did the command and it showed me : Mac OS X, 10.11.3, 15D21

Comment: Ok it's El Capitan. Can you add the results of the command  `diskutil list disk0` ?

Comment: @Jean_JD ok it says... 0: GUID_partition_scheme 250.1 GB disk0... 1: EFI EFI 209.7 MB disk 0s1... 2: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 249.2 GB disk0s2... 3: Apple_Boot Recovery HD 650.0 MB disk0s3

Comment: Ok. I add a response for the recovery mode procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How create an El Capitan installation key from Recovery mode without another running Mac.

Start by downloading El Capitan installer from Windows or Linux from this page: https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT211683

Copy this installer to an exFat formatted key (go beyond the 4 GB limit and readable under Mac os x) and named DMG for convenience.

Start the Mac in Recovery mode, then through the terminal:

1. Create a working partition

List the disk configuration:

```
diskutil list
```

2. Then locate the internal disk, usually disk0

If the structure is ok, we should find a partition named "Macintosh HD" or other with an index disk0s2

If so, create a 50 GB working partition by subtracting those 50 GB from the size of the original partition:
example on a 250 GB disk this will give 200 GB for the main partition and 50 GB for the installation one:

```
diskutil resizevolume disk0s2 200g jhfs+ work 0b
```

This will create the work partition of approximately 50 GB.

3. Then plug in the key and copy the dmg file to the new partition:

   cp /Volumes/DMG/InstallMacOSX.dmg /Volumes/work

It should take a few minutes and if ok, no terminal feedback.

4. Then go to the working directory:

   cd /Volumes/work

and mount the disk image:

```
hdiutil attach InstallMacOSX.dmg
```

Some lines of info should follow which should end with: /Volumes/Install OS X

5. Then recover from the disk image mounted above, the InstallMacOSX.pkg file:

   cp -v /Volumes/"Install OS X"/InstallMacOSX.pkg .

**Please note that the point at the end of the previous line is important. It designates the current directory (/Volumes/work)**

6. Then un-compact the InstallMacOSX.pkg file in a directory (Installer for example) which will be created by the following pkgutil command:

   pkgutil --expand InstallMacOSX.pkg Installer

and position yourself in the created package InstallMacOSX.pkg

```
cd Installer/InstallMacOSX.pkg
```

7. Then un-compact the Payload file using the tar command

   tar -xvf Payload

Move the InstallESD.dmg file to the work directory :

```
mv -v InstallESD.dmg /Volumes/work
```

Then we can create the installation structure :

8)go to the working directory:

```
cd /Volumes/work
```

and clean the installer directory

```
rm -r Installer/*
```

Then continue with this :

```
hdiutil attach InstallESD.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app
hdiutil convert /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -format UDSP -o Installer/Installer
hdiutil resize -size 8g Installer/Installer.sparseimage
hdiutil attach Installer/Installer.sparseimage -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
rm -r /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/Packages
cp -av /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/
cp -av /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/install_build
cp -av /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/install_build
hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app
hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_build
hdiutil resize -size `hdiutil resize -limits Installer/Installer.sparseimage | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $ 1}' `b Installer/Installer.sparseimage
hdiutil convert Installer/Installer.sparseimage -format UDZO -o Installer/Installer
```

First of all create the installation disk partition that we will name CLE by reducing the work partition by 10 GB

```
diskutil resizevolume /Volumes/work 20g jhfs+ CLE 0b
```

If ok we then pass the creation command:

```
asr restore --source Installer/Installer.dmg --target /Volumes/CLE --noprompt --noverify --erase
```

You can now boot on the EC Installer with the Alt key at boot. The name of the Install partition will be "OS X Base System"

I'v tested this method and it's work fine.

The best way, in the "terminal session" is open a new terminal cmd+n and inside do the command :

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Then you connect to the forum (in text mode...) retrieve this post and you can use the copy/paste from the forum tu the initial terminal for each command.

Good luck. ;-

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and i'll tell you if it worked.

Comment: If you have an error or a doubt along the procedure don't hesitate. :-)

Comment: Do a 16 GB key usb is enough? and i didn't understand "and named DMG for convenience". I should paste the InstallMacOSX.dmg on the usb and i would be able to start?

Comment: No, the name DMG for the usb key as no importance it's only to facilitate  the terminal commands. And nothin is terninate àa this point, you have to create the working structure etc.. All the commands are gevin

Comment: Sorry if i'm asking you that kind of questions it's just that i do not want to fail and i want to make sure, i format the usb drive in MBR or GPT?

Comment: The important think is the format : ExFat. The partition scheme (GUID or Mbr) il not important. It's only to copy the file InstallMacOSX.dmg on the internal disk.

Comment: I've modify the and of the procedure. No error now when boot on the installer.

Comment: I have a big problem! After i did the command "hdiutil attach..." it told me "Bus error 10" i waited one minute nothing happened, i was making sure that everything was ok by going to disk utility but it doesn't let me? i want to go back to terminal but it doesn't let me. I did restart my macbook and i'm stuck with a loading bar that stop at the very end (can't boot my macbook) what to do

Comment: it's when i did the command "hdiutil attach InstallMacOSX.dmg"

Comment: Have you 1) create the work directory, 2) copy the file InstallMacOSX.dmg from the key to work directory wait and verify the size `ls -l InstallMacOSX.dmg` the size must be around 6 go

Comment: i do not know if it did mount but when i boot up my macbook it is stuck at 100 and won't go any further, it is stuck at the loading bar i can't do anything

Comment: I made the work directory, i did copy the file InstallMacOSX.dmg to the work directory, i tried to mount but it made an error and i'm stuck with an endless loading bar

Comment: Have you try the recovery mode (cmd+r)

Comment: No. I will try but i think it will make the same problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you have done exactly from the firsts commands?

Comment: First off i did create a work directory on the internal drive which make 50 GB, then plugged my usb to copy InstallMacOSX.dmg and paste it to /Volumes/work, then i (tried) to mount the file BUT, it did tell me "bus error 10" which make me impossible to go to the 4 utilities, since my loading bar is stuck

Comment: You can try a Reset SMC : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and a Reset NVRAM : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063 then retry boot in Recovery mode. If always stuck, may be your internal disk is broken????

Comment: Its always broken... That's weird cuz i did mount on the work directory and that's where it did start to stuck, how the internal drive can be broken like that???

Comment: Have you this Mac for a long time? On a 13-year-old machine, the disk can give up the ghost. Several things to check: the Sata cable that connects the drive to the motherboard can also fail. You can start by opening up the Mac and dusting off and checking it all out. iFixit makes very good detailed tutorials. The memory can also do its own ... The last thing you can try is to start by pressing the alt key to check what is on offer. Otherwise you will have to ask an acquaintance to create an El Capitan key or buy one. Good luck

Comment: No, but i think the user who used this mac because i bought it, has used this mac for a long time, still thank you very much for your help, and i think by buying a key was the most simple thing to do.

Comment: Sorry for you. I still hope that it is not a hardware problem, memory or disk. I still advise you to open it, clean everything and review and clean the memory module and disk connectors with rubbing alcohol, being very careful.
Here is the iFixit link: https://fr.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Unibody_Model_A1342
For information, your Mac supports High Sierra (with an SSD and 8 GB of ram). Have a good evening.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I will be able to help you or not but I will try my best.

I didn't understand your question. Are you saying that you completely erased your Mac including your all personal files, pre-installed apps, and even the operating system?

Your MacBook is too old. I don't think that Macs of 2009 are fit to run the latest version of macOS which we use in 2021. I would rather suggest you buy a new Mac. And you can even go to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/)

But if you don't want to buy a new Mac then I have a possible way. Your Mac won't become as good as the original but it will become usable.

Before you go further, make sure that your Mac meets the minimum requirements for Windows 10. Otherwise, this method won't work.

First, get a Windows PC from someone and also get a 16 GB USB. Download Windows 10 media creation tool from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com//software-download/windows10ISO).

You are going to make Windows 10 bootable USB. (For help see [this video](https://youtu.be/6eJgaz2A8Fc))

After you make a Windows 10 Bootable USB, try to boot your Mac from that USB. If your Mac boots then install Windows 10.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers but it doesn't help me really. First of all i erased macintosh HD, that's only what i did which made me have no OS X, and wdym by pre-installed apps? You mean terminal, disk utility, things like that? if yes then yes there is. And when you tell that my macbook is old, yes but i saw videos peoples with their macbook 2009 that are able to install by usb, it's just i think my model is not compatible, or i did not well made the bootable usb, and about windows 10, same problem, my macbook won't boot by usb, i mean i can try. I do not know...

Comment: I found out that for some mac users using transmac (it's a windows program to make bootable usb for mac) don't work for them, so i can try buying a bootable usb in ebay?

Comment: or shall i upgrade the HDD to SDD

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. The OP wants to install El Capitan which runs perfectly fine on a Mac from 2009. The specific model is mentioned in the question so answering with "make sure that your Mac meets the minimum requirements" isn't all that helpful (we are looking for answers which are correct, not just ideas). Finally you seem to have left out the part where the OP actually can install macOS again.