# Newly installed Debian stuck on loading on MacBook Pro "Core 2 Duo" 2.16

Tags: macbook-pro, unix

I made a successful installation of ***Debian 10.6 32 bits*** on my <strike>2007 MacBook Pro "Core Duo" 2.16 GHz (T2600).</strike> **2007 MacBook Pro 15-Inch "Core 2 Duo" 2.16 2.16 GHz Core 2 Duo (T7400)**

**Intro**.  October 24, 2006
**Disc**.   June 5, 2007
**Order**   MA609LL
**Model**   A1211 (EMC 2120)
**Family**  Core 2 Duo/Late 2006
**ID**  MacBookPro2,2
**RAM** 1 GB    (upgraded to 3GB)
**VRAM**    128 MB

*(MacBook Pro model includes an ATI Mobility Radeon X1600 graphics processor with <strike>256 MB</strike> 128 MB of GDDR3 video memory and dual-link DVI functionality)*

Debian version is: i386/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.6.0-i386-gnome.iso.

After some fixing such as [installing the firmware-linux-nonfree packages](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo),
I now boot and get the following message:

`"fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA"`

Once this message displayed,  the system is stuck.

What does this message mean?
Is there something I could do to unblock the situation?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am conscious this post might not be the best place to be sent here. Though, some of you might have experience on this. I am expecting feedback and leads.

Comment: Feedback: probably better on the Unix Linux stack.

Comment: That message means it is switching from the default/basic VGA to using the Radeon GPU.  It might be an incompatible driver in Linux or a faulty GPU.   You can try booting in Single User Mode (text) and remove the settings you tweaked.

Comment: @SolarMike actually this is the stack that has been delivering the most accurate diagnosis on my issue. Elsewhere the problem is unknown by all... as of now.

Comment: Do you remember if you could boot to the "Debian GNU/Linux Live" version stored on the  USB flash drive?

Comment: @DavidAnderson. I could boot from a Live debian USB i386. The one I have used was "Debian 10.6.0 amd64 i386". It was the DEBIAN [installer](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/) part I use . I also used  a net install "Debian GNU/Linux Live", in the process of testing my options, with which I could boot but the installation failed.

Comment: update on my previous comment. The "Debian GNU/Linux Live" had a "Graphics install of Debian" and a "Try Debian"(if I recall well); the latter did not work for graphics issue; the graphics installer failed to install -- i cant recall why.

Comment: `"fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA"` means that the kernel switches to a framebuffer driver for the console that knows about radeon hardware.  That may not work.  I would suggest reasking this question on the Linux SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have 2007 *MacbookPro2,1* and have found that the Linux Radeon driver does not work.

Without recompiling your kernel your options are extremely limited - you could try an extremely old kernel (before 2009 [KMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting) introduction) which would be hard to find and insecure  or try passing `nomodeset` kernel parameter (which will mean no graphics at all).

To get graphics to work need to do the following:

- Extract the vbios as described in comments in this 2010 bug report [Radeon KMS fails with inaccessible AtomBIOS on systems with (U)EFI boot](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26891):

> 1. boot from latest ubuntu live CD (hold alt, or c, at boot)
> 2. dump the bios
>    `dd if=/dev/mem of=vbios.bin bs=65536 skip=12 count=1`
> 3. move it to your partition's /lib/firmware/radeon/vbios.bin

Based on this Archlinux forums thread [Load custom Radeon firmware for Macbook Pro](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139511) thread I saved `vbios.bin` to `/usr/lib/firmware/radeon/vbios.bin`.

- Check it as described in link above:

> b) You can verify the correctness with:
> hexdump -C vbios.bin | head -n 1
> 00000000  55 aa 7d e9 7f 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |U.}.............|
> the first two bytes must be 55 aa, also later in the dump you see some copyright
> notices. :-)

- Patch [radeon_bios.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_bios.c) source to read this file and recompile kernel.

This method has worked for me for the last several years.  Occasionally `radeon_bios.c` changes and the patch in the links above is outdated.
As of last month (October 2020) the following patch will work with [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) kernel.  For others you may need to manually adjust it.

```
--- archlinux-linux/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_bios.c.orig   2020-04-08 13:12:37.572725381 +0200
+++ archlinux-linux/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_bios.c    2020-04-08 13:26:48.700908967 +0200
@@ -33,6 +33,7 @@
 #include <drm/drm_device.h>

 #include "atom.h"
+#include <linux/firmware.h>
 #include "radeon.h"
 #include "radeon_reg.h"

@@ -60,15 +61,18 @@ static bool igp_read_bios_from_vram(stru
    vram_base = pci_resource_start(rdev->pdev, 0);
    bios = ioremap(vram_base, size);
    if (!bios) {
+       DRM_ERROR("No bios\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (size == 0 || bios[0] != 0x55 || bios[1] != 0xaa) {
+       DRM_ERROR("Invalid bios\n");
        iounmap(bios);
        return false;
    }
    rdev->bios = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (rdev->bios == NULL) {
+       DRM_ERROR("alloc fail\n");
        iounmap(bios);
        return false;
    }
@@ -77,6 +81,41 @@ static bool igp_read_bios_from_vram(stru
    return true;
 }

+static bool radeon_read_bios_from_firmware(struct radeon_device *rdev)
+{
+   const uint8_t __iomem *bios;
+   resource_size_t size;
+   const struct firmware *fw = NULL;
+
+   request_firmware(&fw, "radeon/vbios.bin", rdev->dev);
+   if (!fw) {
+           DRM_ERROR("No bios\n");
+           return false;
+   }
+   size = fw->size;
+   bios = fw->data;
+
+   if (!bios) {
+           DRM_ERROR("No bios\n");
+           return false;
+   }
+
+   if (size == 0 || bios[0] != 0x55 || bios[1] != 0xaa) {
+           DRM_ERROR("wrong sig\n");
+           release_firmware(fw);
+           return false;
+   }
+   rdev->bios = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
+   if (rdev->bios == NULL) {
+           DRM_ERROR("alloc fail\n");
+           release_firmware(fw);
+           return false;
+   }
+   memcpy(rdev->bios, bios, size);
+   release_firmware(fw);
+   return true;
+}
+
 static bool radeon_read_bios(struct radeon_device *rdev)
 {
    uint8_t __iomem *bios, val1, val2;
@@ -663,7 +702,9 @@ bool radeon_get_bios(struct radeon_devic
    bool r;
    uint16_t tmp;

-   r = radeon_atrm_get_bios(rdev);
+   r = radeon_read_bios_from_firmware(rdev);
+   if (!r)
+       r = radeon_atrm_get_bios(rdev);
    if (!r)
        r = radeon_acpi_vfct_bios(rdev);
    if (!r)
```

Comment: Another option to consider if you are just wanting to use the MBP rather than install Linux in particular is to install Windows 10.  It works fine on my 2007 MBP without any fiddling required.

Comment: @ix07 Thank you for the time spent on this. I have to study your guide here before in jump on doing that. There is probably a learning curve as well as I have never recompiled a kernel, need to study that. I will keep you posted

Comment: @ix07 I want to keep using the MBP because it is a good machine. I cannot use it with OSX, too slow. The reason I wanted to install Linux is It only has 3GB-ish RAM. Also I have tried with installing ubuntu but came across issues with booting as the MBP EFI boot is 32 bits and now Ubuntu is only 64 bits. Debian looked like the good option. About Windows, considering the RAM limits on MBP, I am wondering if this would work nicely with windows. Any thoughts / advices with Windows and a MBP with 3GB RAM...? just in case

Comment: If you use [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) bootloader (32 bit) it will start 64 bit Linux no problem but you still get the Radeon issue above.  My MBP also has 3GB and I triple boot OSX (El Capitan), Archlinux (64 bit) and Windows 10 (64 bit) on it.  All are usable for internet/Office tasks but all are a bit slow - not much difference.  Of the 3 Windows is the easiest to install.  OSX Lion is the last supported release but has little software - El Capitan works but needs [patching](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/os-x-el-capitan-on-unsupported-macs.1889851/) to work.

Comment: @ix07 After researching a while on why can't i boot a 64 bit live-Linux, I came across Rod Smith's posts (the guy who made refind) that helped. The conclusion was I have a MBP with EFI boot 32 bit. Based on the serial number on the MBP, I have found the spec : it is a core 2 Duo T7400 (note it is not T7600). I apology for that change

Comment: @DavidAnderson I could not add you in the comments to ix07. I made some edit - double checked - in the initial post. I have a 64 bits processor and a 32 bit EFI boot.

Comment: @David Anderson It does work with previous burned DVD. Lately I have burned RW DVD and the MBP DVD drive did not like them. What is your idea?

Comment: @David Anderson - to your question, Yes i can install snow leopard.I have two questions : 1 - What difference does it make installing from a DVD rather than USB?

Comment: @DavidAnderson 2 - I would be happy with a Xubuntu 18 (I use a Xubuntu 20.04 on a MacBook Air, perfect!) but It would NOT solve the radeon issue mentioned here, whatever distro I use. Am I correct here?

Comment: @DavidAnderson please apologies for my ignorance but my understanding is that i would hit the same issue with (X/L/K)Ubuntu as well. How would installing Xubuntu 64 bit work around the radeon driver issue?

Comment: @Jerome, you are correct, it's a kernel issue. I'm fairly sure no post 2009 (approx) kernel will work unless patched as that is when KMS was introduced. It's possible Ubuntu patched it (I never tested) but I doubt it as it's only really an issue for old mbp and imac.

Comment: +1 @lx07 I guess I should go with Windows then. Never happened to be buying a windows license in my entire life... ironically for a MBP. Let me try you solution this week end... if i am lucky!

Comment: @Ix07 genuine interrogation. When I installed Debian from the boot USB, video worked neatly. It looked I had no video driver issue. What is the reason that makes the video driver a problem after installation? (If it can install with no video issue, why does this happen after)

Comment: @Jermone, I don't know how it does that - I suppose it doesn't use Linux kernel or doesn't try to load Radeon driver.  Perhaps it somehow continues to use the EFI framebuffer driver (same as rEFInd does and macOS does before Filevault unlock screen) but that is a guess.  Your error is when kernel switches framebuffer driver (`fb:`) to the Radeon kernel driver (`radeondrmfb`) from the [EFI framebuffer driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/fb/efifb.html) (`EFI VGA`) which is a standard part of Linux boot process (or any other OS boot process I guess).

Comment: @Ix07, this is great material. Yhank you. I have tried to install windows 10 instead. Believe it or not, I have another issue on booting windows from USB. The reason is that: refind install can not detect that the EFI boot is 32 bit. Reason being : i install it from Debian and the installer cannot detect that bitness of the EFI boot, it just assumes it is EFI 64bit because the machine is 64 bit!  Finally it makes refind unusable ! GRUB is installed to the ESP so what are my options for installing windows 10? Can I do that from the Grub?

Comment: @Jerome, you should ask another question for that.  Your MBP will likely not boot installer from USB though - the firmware will only boot OSX from external drive if it is the same as mine.  You need to either burn ISO to DVD and use optical drive, install using a virtual machine with raw disk access or you can (as I did) remove the drive from MBP, put it in a Windows machine to install then put it back.  rEFInd you can install manually by just copying files - see [Installing rEFInd Manually Using MacOS](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx)

Comment: @Ix07 That was my thought as well: asking a new question. About refind, I had a mail conversation with Rod Smith , he wrote "if you've installed a
64-bit version of Linux, you'll be able to boot it from rEFInd only
through GRUB; a 32-bit rEFInd won't be able to load a 64-bit kernel."

Comment: @ix07 The alternative I have now would be to follow your steps thoroughly and recompile the kernel. I have never done that, I had a look, it is massively impressive for a newbie. But whatever ...

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Since current stable release is now 10.7.0, this answer will use this release instead of 10.6.0.

This answer modifies the install procedure used by the OP in the following ways.

- The non-free packages will be included in the installation ISO file. This will avoid encountering any problems downloading non-free packages after completing an installation.
- While the initial installation will be 32 bit, the final installation will be 64 bit.
- The installations will BIOS boot from the internal drive.
- The use of the legacy Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table scheme will be used. If the use of the GUID Partition Table (GPT) scheme or the [Hybrid MBR](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) scheme is desired, the user will need to make the appropriate modifications to this answer.

The Debian installation ISO files can be burned to a DVD. These DVDs are configured to be either BIOS or EFI booted. However, early Intel Macs, such as [the OP's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279559/alternatives-to-installing-ubuntu-from-bootable-usb-and-bootable-dvd), can not boot from a DVD with such a configuration. Also, not all Intel Macs can BIOS boot from an USB port. This would include the OP's model Mac.

A brief outline of the procedure is given below. A rather lengthly explanation will follow.

- Use another computer to download the 32 bit Debian installation ISO file which includes additional software for graphical video hardware.
- Use the `dd` command or Rufus to transfer the 32 bit Debian installation ISO file to a USB flash drive.
- Use the Mac Startup Manager to 32 bit EFI boot from the USB flash drive and install a 32 bit BIOS booting Debian. During the installation, an additional `ext4` formatted partition will be created on the internal drive for new installations.
- Use the Mac or another computer to download a 64 bit Debian installation ISO file which includes additional software for graphical video hardware. Also, download a 64 bit Debian kernel image (`vmlinuz`) file and a 64 bit initial RAM disk (`initrd.gz`) file. *These two special files allow a Debian installer to be booted from an internal drive.*
- Transfer the 64 bit Debian installation ISO, Debian kernel image and initial RAM disk files to the partition created on the internal drive for new installations. If another computer is used to download, then the transfer can be accomplished by using a FAT formatted USB flash drive or `sftp`.
- Boot to Grub, then use the Grub command line to 64 bit BIOS boot from the partition on the internal drive created for new installations. Install a 64 bit BIOS booting Debian.
- Remove internal partition created for new installations and reclaim the space for use by Debian.
- (optional) Bless the Mac to BIOS boot by default.

The steps to install Debian are as follows.

> Hint: For a better view, click on an image or open an image in a new window.

1. *Use another computer to download the current 32 bit Debian installation ISO file which includes additional software for graphical video hardware.* This file can be found [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.7.0+nonfree/i386/iso-dvd/). At present, this would be the file named `firmware-10.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso`. Here, the assumption have been made that all files are downloaded to the users default `Downloads` folder.
2. *Transfer the 32 bit Debian installation ISO file to a USB flash drive.* Insert the flash drive a USB port. Use the following instructions based on the type of operating system.

   - **OS X (macOS):** Use the `diskutil list` command to determined the device identifier. If the disk identifier is not `disk1`, then make the appropriate substitution when entering the first line.

     ```
     DISK=disk1
     diskutil unmountdisk $DISK
     sudo dd if=~/Downloads/firmware-10.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/r$DISK bs=1m
     ```
   - **Linux:** Use the `lsblk` command to determined the device identifier. If the disk identifier is not `sdb`, then make the appropriate substitution when entering the first line.

     ```
     DISK=sdb
     sudo umount /dev/$DISK*
     sudo dd if=~/Downloads/firmware-10.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/$DISK bs=1M
     ```
   - **Windows:** A third party tool will be required. One such tool is [rufus](https://rufus.ie). For example, if a volume on the flash drive has been assigned the drive letter `E:`, then the current version of rufus should be configured as shown below.

     > Note: A flash drive can be selected even if the drive has not been assigned a drive letter.

     [image]

     When finished configuring, select the `Start` button. When the popup shown below appears, select `Write in DD Image mode` followed by the `OK` button.

     [image]

     > Note: After successfully transferring the `firmware-10.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso` file to a USB flash drive, a partition on the flash drive may be mounted and modified by Windows. While these modifications will not interfere with the installation of Debian, the modifications will prevent verification of the flash drive by a SHA checksum or comparison to the original file.

     Other possible third party tools are outlined in the ["In Windows" section of the Arch Linux document "USB flash installation medium"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_medium#In_Windows).
3. *Create a MBR Partition Table on the internal drive.* Insert the flash drive in a USB port of the Mac where Debian is to be installed. Start or restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear. Choose the external drive icon with the label `EFI Boot`. When the image below appears, pick `Advanced options ...`, then select `... Rescue mode`.

   [image: Grub menu]

   Continue until a similar image to the one below appears. Pick `Do not use a root file system`, then select `Execute a Shell in the installer environment` and finally, `<Continue>`.

   [image: pick root file system]

   Enter the following commands. When asked to continue, enter a `y`.

   ```
   parted /dev/sda mklabel msdos
   parted /dev/sda mkpart primary hfs 1mib 100%
   reboot
   ```

   If the Mac does not boot from the flash drive, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the external drive icon labeled `EFI boot`.
4. *Install a 32 bit BIOS booting Debian.* When the image below appears, select either `Graphical install` or `Install`. Here, `Install` was chosen, as shown below.

   [image: Install]

   Continue with the installation. When an image similar to below appears, select `<No>`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `Manual`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `(sda)`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `<Yes>`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `FREE SPACE`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   Here you want to create a new primary partition at the beginning of the available space. When asked for a size, enter a size smaller than the maximum size. This value can be determined by subtracting from the maximum size the desired size of the swap partition and the size of the temporary partition needed for the 64 bit Debian installation files. In this example, the swap partition will be 6 GB and the temporary partition will be 16 GB. The difference is shown below.

   ```
   128.8 GB - 6 GB - 16 GB = 106.8 GB
   ```

   The size value you will enter most likely will be different from the value of `106.8 GB` entered in this example. Configure the rest of the partition settings as shown below, then select `Done setting up the partition`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `FREE SPACE`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   Here you want to create a new logical partition at the end of the available space. When asked for a size, enter the desired size of the swap partition. For this example, the value was already stated to be 6 GB. You should enter the value you have already determined. Configure the rest of the partition setting as shown below, then select `Done setting up the partition`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `FREE SPACE`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   Here you want to create a new primary partition from the available space. When asked for a size, do not change the value shown. Configure the rest of the partition setting as shown below, then select `Done setting up the partition`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   For this example, the result is shown below. Select `Finish partitioning and write changes to disk`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `<Yes>`.

   [image: Partition disks]

   Proceed with the installation. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, either choose a mirror or avoid using a mirror. In this example, the mirror is avoided, thus decreased the time required to install. Avoiding the mirror can be accomplished by selecting `<No>`. If `<No>` is missing as shown below, then avoiding the mirror can be accomplished by selecting `<Go Back>`, then selecting `<Yes>`.

   [image: Configure the package manager]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, probably the only software required is the `standard system utilities`. In this example, a `Debian desktop environment` will be omitted to decrease the time required to install. The `SSH server` will be included, so `sftp` will be available to transfer files later. Below is the configuration used in this example. When done making choices, select `Continue`.

   [image: Software selection]

   Proceed with the installation. If an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `<Yes>`.

   [image: Install the Grub boot loader on a hard disk]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `/dev/sda`.

   > Note: When using earlier version of the Debian installer, the device `/dev/sda` needed to be manually entered.

   [image: Install the Grub boot loader on a hard disk]

   Finish installing Debian.
5. *Create a 64 bit Debian installer on an internal drive partition.*

   > Note: The instructions given in this step were derived from section [4.3. Preparing Files for USB Memory Stick Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.en.html) of the [Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/index.en.html). The main difference is a partition on the internal drive will be used instead of a USB memory stick (flash drive).

   Start by booting to Debian. If the Mac does not boot to Debian (via Grub) by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, login as root. Otherwise, login using the default username, open a Terminal window and enter the command shown below.

   ```
   su --login
   ```

   Enter a following command to permit writing to the `/dev/sda3` partition, which has been assigned the `/installation` mount point.

   ```
   chmod a+w /installation
   ```

   Transfer, to the `/installation` mount point, the three files required to install a 64 bit Debian. One of these files is the current 64 bit Debian installation ISO file which includes additional software for graphical video hardware. This file can be found [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-dvd/). At present, this would be the file named `firmware-10.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`. The other two files are the text based installer image files required when booting from the internal drive. At present this would be [vmlinuz and initrd.gz](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/). Below are various ways to transfer these files. Choose one way or find another way.

   > Note: A choice below can depend on which predefined collections of software are currently installed.

   - Use another computer to download and transfer the files to a FAT formatted USB flash drive. Use either the `cp` command or the Files application to copy from the USB flash drive to the `/installation` mount point.
   - Use another computer to download the files. Use `sftp` on this other computer to transfer the files to the `/installation` mount point on the Mac. Enter the command `hostname -I` on the Mac to get an IP address.
   - Use the FireFox ESR application to download the files from the web. Use either the `cp` command or the Files application to copy the downloaded files to the `/installation` mount point.

   When finished, shutdown the Mac. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, then enter the command below instead.

   ```
   shutdown -P now
   ```

   Remove any USB flash drives that may be plugged into the Mac.
6. *Replace the 32 bit Debian with a 64 bit Debian.* Start by booting to Grub. If the Mac does not boot to Grub by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, press the <kbd>C</kbd> key.

   [image: GNU GRUB]

   Enter the commands given below to boot from the `/dev/sda3` partition. This sequence of commands was derived from section [5.1.5. Booting from Linux using LILO or GRUB](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s01.en.html#boot-initrd) of the [Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/index.en.html).

   ```
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ext2
   set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
   linux /vmlinuz
   initrd /initrd.gz
   boot
   ```

   Proceed with the installation of Debian. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `Manual`.

   [image: 64 Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `#1  primary`.

   [image: 64 Partition disks]

   Configure the partition setting as shown below, then select `Done setting up the partition`.

   [image: 64 Partition disks]

   For this example, the result is shown below. Select `Finish partitioning and write changes to disk`.

   [image: 64 Partition disks]

   When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select `<Yes>`.

   > Note: This is the point where the 32 bit Debian is deleted.

   [image: 64 Partition disks]

   Continue with the installation of Debian. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, select the line containing `/dev/sda`.

   > Note: When using earlier version of the Debian installer, the device `/dev/sda` needed to be manually entered.

   [image: 64 Install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk]

   Finish installing Debian.
7. *Remove the partition with the installation files and extend the Debian partition.*

   Open a Terminal application window. Enter the commands given below.

   ```
   su
   sudo parted /dev/sda unit s \ print
   ```

   The output produced in this example from entering these commands is shown below.

   ```
   dma@debian:~$ su
   Password: 
   root@debian:/home/dma# sudo parted /dev/sda unit s \ print
   Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 251658240s
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: msdos
   Disk Flags: 

   Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system     Flags
    1      2048s       208592895s  208590848s  primary   ext4            boot
    3      208592896s  239937535s  31344640s   primary   ext4
    2      239939582s  251656191s  11716610s   extended
    5      239939584s  251656191s  11716608s   logical   linux-swap(v1)
   ```

   From the second row of entries in the above table, record the entry in the `End` column. This would be the row where the `Number` entry is `3`. In this example the entry in the `End` column is `239937535s`. The entry you will record will most likely be different. Next, enter the commands and entries shown below. Replace the entry of `239937535s` with the your recorded entry from the table.

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sda rm 3
   sudo parted /dev/sda resizepart 1
   yes
   239937535s
   sudo parted /dev/sda unit s \ print
   ```

   The output produced in this example from these commands and entries is shown below.

   ```
   root@debian:/home/dma# sudo parted /dev/sda rm 3
   Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

   root@debian:/home/dma# sudo parted /dev/sda resizepart 1
   Warning: Partition /dev/sda1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
   Yes/No? yes
   End?  [107GB]? 239937535s
   Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

   root@debian:/home/dma# sudo parted /dev/sda unit s \ print
   Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 251658240s
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: msdos
   Disk Flags: 

   Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system     Flags
    1      2048s       239937535s  239935488s  primary   ext4            boot
    2      239939582s  251656191s  11716610s   extended
    5      239939584s  251656191s  11716608s   logical   linux-swap(v1)
   ```

   The first partition in the new table should now occupy the space previously occupied by the third partition. Next, enter the command given below to expand mounted filesystem to fill the partition.

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
   ```

   The output produced in this example from entering this command is shown below.

   ```
   root@debian:/home/dma# sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
   resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
   Filesystem at /dev/sda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
   old_desc_blocks = 13, new_desc_blocks = 15
   The filesystem on /dev/sda1 is now 29991936 (4k) blocks long.
   ```

   The computation below can be used to verify the space used by the filesystem in blocks matches the number of sectors in the partition.

   ```
   29991936 blocks * 4196 bytes/block / 512 bytes/sector = 239935488 sectors
   ```

   Finally, enter the commands given below to close the Terminal window.

   ```
   exit
   exit
   ```

   Restarting the Mac would be recommended.

### Setting BIOS Booting as the Default

If a BIOS booting Debian is the only operating system installed on a Mac, then the Mac should automatically boot to Debian. However, if BIOS booting has not be set as the default, there may be a delay before booting begins. Otherwise, the Mac Startup Manager can be used to boot Debian. To set BIOS booting as the default, boot from an OS X (macOS) installation DVD or USB flash drive, open a Terminal window and enter the command given below.

```
bless --device /dev/disk0 --setBoot --legacy
```

The version of OS X (macOS) chosen must be compatible with your Mac. The instructions for creating a Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) installation USB flash drive can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive/400475#400475).

### Debian Downloads

10.6.0 Release

- 32 Bit: [firmware-10.6.0-i386-DVD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.6.0+nonfree/i386/iso-dvd/)
- 32 Bit Gnome Live: [debian-live-10.6.0-i386-gnome+nonfree.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.6.0-live+nonfree/i386/iso-hybrid/)
- 64 Bit: [firmware-10.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.6.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/)
- 64 Bit Gnome Live: [debian-live-10.6.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.6.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/)

Current (10.7.0) Release

- 32 Bit: [firmware-10.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/archive/10.7.0+nonfree/i386/iso-dvd/)
- 32 Bit Gnome Live: [debian-live-10.7.0-i386-gnome+nonfree.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/)
- 64 Bit: [firmware-10.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-dvd/)
- 64 Bit Gnome Live: [debian-live-10.7.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)
- 64 Bit: HD Media [vmlinuz and initrd.gz](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/)
- 64 Bit Graphical HD Media: [vmlinuz and initrd.gz](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/gtk/)

### References

[Hybrid MBRs: The Good, the Bad, and the So Ugly You'll Tear Your Eyes Out](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html)
[Alternatives to installing Ubuntu from bootable USB and bootable DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279559/alternatives-to-installing-ubuntu-from-bootable-usb-and-bootable-dvd)
[Rufus](https://rufus.ie)
[In Windows section of USB flash installation medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_medium#In_Windows)
[4.3. Preparing Files for USB Memory Stick Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.en.html)
[Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/index.en.html)
[5.1.5. Booting from Linux using LILO or GRUB](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s01.en.html#boot-initrd)
[Creating a USB Flash Drive Installer from a Snow Leopard ISO File](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive/400475#400475)