# Can a version of Windows newer than Vista be installed on MacBookPro2,2 2006 Core 2 Duo?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, startup

Apple documents state my MacBookPro2,2 2006 Core 2 Duo 2.16 MHz will not run Windows versions newer than Vista. However, I burned a 32 bit Windows 7 ISO to a DVD, after converting the ISO to DVD/CD master in the Disk Utility. The resulting DVD worked. I tried same procedure with a 32 bit Windows 10 ISO. The Mac froze at a black screen with a message asking for a boot choice 1, 2. Why did booting from the Windows 10 DVD fail?

I understand that my Mac has a 32 bit EFI, but the processor is 64 bit. I also understand there are issues with booting from an USB flash drive, which is why I used a DVD. Are there other methods to install newer versions of Windows on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You model Mac can only support only one boot method when booting from the optical drive. The 32 bit Windows 7 installer ISO provide by Microsoft can only be BIOS booted and therefore offers no problems when burn to a DVD. However, any of the Windows 10 installer ISO files provided by Microsoft can be either BIOS or UEFI booted. Using a DVD burned from one of these ISO files to boot your Mac will result in your Mac hanging as described in your question. This is true for both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the Windows 10 installer ISO file.

Several answers involving installing Windows 10 on your model Mac have already been posted. See the question [Installing windows on a MacBook Pro 15-Inch “Core 2 Duo” without Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406506/installing-windows-on-a-macbook-pro-15-inch-core-2-duo-without-mac-os-x).

Note the following:

- According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-system-requirements-6d4e9a79-66bf-7950-467c-795cf0386715), a computer needs at least 1 GB of RAM in order to install 32 bit Windows 10 and at least 2 GB of RAM in order to install 64 bit Windows 10. Your Mac was shipped with 1 GB of RAM, but is capable of being upgraded to at least 2 GB.
- You do not need a license to install and test Windows 10. However, to continue using Windows 10 will require a license. You may be able to install a licensed Windows 7, then upgrade to Windows 10 for free. This was true as of early in 2020. I do not know if this is still true today. Also, if a licensed Windows 10 was previous installed on your Mac, then you will be able to use this existing license.
- [Apple](https://militarycac.com/MAC/Boot_Camp_Install-Setup_10.6.pdf) only supports running 32 bit Windows XP SP2 or Vista on your model Mac. Therefore, the drivers provided by Apple may or may to work with a 32 or 64 bit Windows 10. However do to the age of your Mac, many of the necessary drivers will probably already be included in the Windows 10 installer software or will be downloaded automatically from Microsoft.

### Using USB to Install Windows 10

The basic steps are outline below. An optical drive is not used to install Windows 10.

- Use a USB port to install a 32 bit BIOS booting Debian Linux. This will include the Grub boot loader.
- Use Debian Linux to copy the Windows 10 installation files to a NTFS formatted volume on the internal drive.
- Use Grub to BIOS boot the Windows 10 installer on the internal drive.
- Install a BIOS booting Windows 10. This will overwrite Grub and Debian Linux.
- Expand the Windows 10 partition to consume the space occupied by the partitions containing the Windows 10 installer files and the Debian Linux swap space.

A more detailed version of above steps is given below. These steps can be used to install either a 32 bit or 64 bit version of Windows 10.

1. *Install 32 bit BIOS booting Debian Linux.* Follow steps 1 through 4 given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16/409448#409448) with the following exception. When asked to `Configure the package manager`, choose a `Debian archive mirror country` followed by a `Debian archive mirror`.
2. *Prepare a partition for the Windows installation files.* Start by booting to Debian. If the Mac does not boot to Debian (via Grub) by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, login as root. Otherwise, login using the default username, open a Terminal window and enter the command shown below.

   ```
   su --login
   ```

   The middle partition on the internal drive (`/dev/sda3`) contains an ext4 formatted volume. The command given below will replace this volume with a NTFS formatted volume. A connection to the internet is required.

   ```
   apt update
   apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils ntfs-3g parted
   sed -i '/\/installation/d' /etc/fstab
   umount /dev/sda3
   sfdisk --part-type /dev/sda 3 7
   partprobe
   mkfs.ntfs -L WINSTALL -Q /dev/sda3
   mount /dev/sda3 /installation
   ```
3. *Create a Windows 10 installer on an internal drive partition.*

   Enter a following command to permit writing to the `/home` folder.

   ```
   chmod a+w /home
   ```

   Transfer, to the `/home` folder, [the ISO file required to install Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). In the case of this example, this would be the `Win10_20H2_English_x64.iso` file. If your file is different, then make the appropriate substitutions in this step. Below are various ways to transfer this file. Choose one way or find another way.

   > Note: A choice below can depend on which predefined collections of software are currently installed.

   - Use another computer to download and transfer the ISO file to a ExFAT formatted USB flash drive. Use either the `cp` command or the Files application to copy from the USB flash drive to the `/home` folder.
   - Use another computer to download the ISO file. Use `sftp` on this other computer to transfer the ISO file to the `/home` folder on the Mac. Enter the command `hostname -I` on the Mac to get an IP address.
   - Use the FireFox ESR application to download the ISO file from the web. Use either the `mv` command or the Files application to move the downloaded ISO file to the `/home` folder.

   Next, enter the commands given below to copy the Windows 10 installation files from the mounted ISO file to the `/installation` mount point.

   > Note: The `boot.wim` and `install.wim` files are very large and therefore will take a while to be copied.

   ```
   mkdir -p /media/iso
   mount -o loop,ro /home/Win10_20H2_English_x64.iso /media/iso
   cp -Rv /media/iso/* /installation
   ```

   When finished, shutdown the Mac. If a Debian desktop environment was not installed, then enter the command below instead.

   ```
   shutdown -P now
   ```

   Remove any USB flash drives that may be plugged into the Mac.
4. *Replace the 32 bit Debian with Windows 10.* Start by booting to Grub. If the Mac does not boot to Grub by default, then restart the Mac and immediately hold <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Select the internal drive icon labeled `Windows`. When an image similar to the one shown below appears, press the <kbd>C</kbd> key.

   [image: GNU Grub]

   Enter the commands given below to boot from the `/dev/sda3` partition.

   ```
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ntfs
   insmod ntldr
   set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
   parttool (hd0,msdos1) type=7 boot+
   ntldr /bootmgr
   boot
   ```

   Proceed with the installation of Windows.  When you reach the window shown in the image below, select `Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)`.

   [image]

   When the window shown in the image below appears, leave `Drive 0 Partition 1` highlighted and click on the `Format` button. Next, click on the `OK` button in the popup window. Finally, click on the `Next` button.

   [image]

   Proceed with the installation of Windows 10.
5. *Install the Boot Camp Support Software (Windows Support Software).* The Boot Camp Support Software is on the Snow Leopard installation DVD. The files can be accessed from Windows. Officially, only 32 bit versions of Windows can be installed on your Mac. Since I do not have your model Mac, I can not predict how difficult it will be to the adapt the software for use with a 64 bit Windows. You should consult [lx07's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406506/installing-windows-on-a-macbook-pro-15-inch-core-2-duo-without-mac-os-x/406560#406560) for more information.

   A Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) ISO file can be downloaded from the website [Mac OS X Snow Leopard Install DVD](https://archive.org/details/SnowLeopardInstall). You should verify the download by computing the SHA256 hash value. The `Get-FileHash` Power Shell cmdlet can be used to compute a SHA256 hash value. Entering `Get-FileHash` along with the path to the downloaded file in a Power Shell window should produce the following SHA256 hash value.

   ```
   CBEEB2378C40B20A9B06236F567DE593E9030A0A865515B50CF6D35833E25CD5
   ```

   Under Windows 10, the Boot Camp Support Software can be accessed by mounting this ISO file.
6. *Remove unnecessary partitions and extend the Windows 10 partition.* Boot to Windows 10 desktop. Next, right click on the `Start` button and select `Disk Management`. A windows similar to the one shown below will appear.

   [image]

   Right click on the last partition shown for Disk 0. Select `Delete Volume…`, as shown below. In the popup window, click on the `Yes` button.

   [image]

   Right click on the free space shown for Disk 0. Select `Delete Partition…`. In the popup window, click on the `Yes` button.

   [image]

   Right click on the partition with the volume label `WINSTALL`. Select `Delete Volume…`. In the popup window, click on the `Yes` button.

   [image]

   Right click on the partition with the drive letter `C:`. Select `Extend Volume…`. In the popup window, click on the `Next` button. Again, in the next popup window, click on the `Next` button. In the next popup window, click on the `Finish` button.

   [image]

   The result is shown below.

   [image]

   Exit the Disk Management application.

### Setting BIOS Booting as the Default

If a BIOS booting Windows is the only operating system installed on a Mac, then the Mac should automatically boot to Windows. However, if BIOS booting has not be set as the default, there may be a delay before booting begins. Otherwise, the Mac Startup Manager can be used to boot Windows. Below are two methods for setting BIOS booting as the default.

- ***Method 1:*** Boot from an OS X (macOS) installation DVD or USB flash drive, open a Terminal window and enter the command given below.

  ```
   bless --device /dev/disk0 --setBoot --legacy
  ```

  The version of OS X (macOS) chosen must be compatible with your Mac. The instructions for creating a Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) installation USB flash drive can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400472/how-to-create-a-bootable-os-x-snow-leopard-usb-drive/400475#400475).
- ***Method 2:*** A successful installation of the Boot Camp Support Software (Window Support Software) will include the creation of the Boot Camp control panel for Windows.

  To set the default operating system in Windows:

  1. In Windows, click the Boot Camp icon in the system tray and choose Boot Camp Control Panel.

     > Note: Your screen may look different, depending on which computer you’re using.
  2. Select the startup disk with the Windows operating system as the default.
  3. If you want to start up that operating system now, click Restart.